# xslt : xml transformation, need soql query as output

Tags: xslt-1.0

Thanks for the solution.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>18029</current>
                <limit>5000000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <upsertResponse>
            <result>
                <created>false</created>
                <id xsi:nil="true"/>
                <success>false</success>
            </result>
            <result>
                <created>false</created>
                <id xsi:nil="true"/>
                <success>false</success>
            </result>
            <result>
                <created>false</created>
                <id xsi:nil="true"/>
                <success>false</success>
            </result>
        </upsertResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

for the above xml as input to xslt, the output is below one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soql>select (select Id from contacts where AccountId in (SELECT  AccountId from Opportunity where id in ())), (select Id from opportunities where id in()) from account where id in (SELECT  AccountId from Opportunity where id in())</soql>
```

if all the  success tag values are false in the given input xml, the `<soql>` tag should not be generated. i mean output should be empty

eventually what i need is valid SOQL, so that i can query sales force, for the above given xml input the output generated is not a valid SOQL. henceforth i cannot query sales force.

so where the changes in xslt needs to be done, need your help

Thanks

Comment: please show the xslt code you tried and that failed. Please do it editing the question, not inside comments.

Comment: There is no place in your xslt where you would output a "select", so how would you expect to get your output? Nor do you output a `soql` tag, but an `in` tag? That's pretty far away I'd say.

Comment: i replaced in with soql tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">

<xsl:variable name="ids">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ns:result[ns:success='true']">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns:id" />
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<soql>
    <xsl:text>select (select Id from contacts where AccountId in (SELECT  AccountId from Opportunity where id in (</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ids"/>
    <xsl:text>))), (select Id from opportunities where id in(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ids"/>
    <xsl:text>)) from account where id in (SELECT  AccountId from Opportunity where id in(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ids"/>
    <xsl:text>))</xsl:text>
</soql>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when there is  success = false (<success>false</success>) in the given input xml, the <soql> tag should not be generated. i mean output should be empty.
so where the changes in xslt needs to be done, can u please help me.
thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: when there is success = true(<success>true</success>) in the given input xml, the <soql> tag should be generated which contains the ids

Comment: You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: michael i am sorry if my information is not in place, if success = false in the given input xml (<success>false</success>) then no output should be generated. i mean <soql> tag should not be exists. if success = true(<success>true</success>) in the given input xml, the <soql> tag should be generated which contains the ids. am i clear now

Comment: No, you are still contradicting yourself. Suppose you have one success=true result, and one success=false result. Your first rule says to not output anything, your second rule says to do the output.

Comment: edited the question, can you please look and let me know if any further information required

Comment: You could wrap the output in `<xsl:if test="//ns:result[ns:success='true']">`. That will output a result only if there is at least one result where success=true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115226/discussion-between-user2587669-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: Let us not. ----------

Comment: wrapped the output in <xsl:if test="//ns:result[ns:success='true']">, worked for me. thanks for your help